# How to solve circular dependencies between JARs?

Tags: java, jar, dependencies, circular-dependency

I am working on a big project with a lot of JARs and for sure no documentation exists!! :(

To ensure that there is no memory leakage in the application, I've used [JBoss Tattletale](http://www.jboss.org/tattletale) to check for circular dependencies between Jars and unfortunately I have found many.

Can you please guide me on how to solve circular dependencies between JARs??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you able to repackage the jars or rebuild them from scratch? If so try and create a third jar that contains the common code or dependencies. Besides that, why should circular dependencies between jars cause memory leaks as long as each jar exists only once, and there are no custom classloaders that don't use class repositories?

Comment: Circular dependencies between JARs, while not good, *do not* cause memory leaks.

Comment: Please check the third paragraph @ [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency#Problems_of_circular_dependencies) link.  It is stated that circular dependencies can cause memory leakage by preventing the garbage collector from deallocating unused objects

Comment: @M.ES circular dependencies cause leaks only when reference counting method of GC is used. Java uses a mark and sweep type of GC (I read this long ago, and its GC method may have since changed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by `memory leakage`, you mean `more memory than necessary is consumed` or `my jar(s) is(are) too fat`, then, you may want to investigate [Proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/).

I am creating large maven projects, with many dependencies on many libraries, which themselves have dependencies to other libraries. However, I am not using all the code in all libraries. Proguard basically helps me trim and remove all unnecessary code.

It is really a clean tool doing the job for me. I create a huge fat jar with all my dependencies, configure my entry points in my code and then it shrinks everything.

Comment: +JVersty Thanks for the tool! I think it will solve my problem. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can break dependencies by [dependency inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle). To avoid and resolve circular dependencies, it helps to design a tiered architecture.

That said, the circular dependencies do not cause memory leakage. But breaking circular dependencies has a lot of positive effects, mainly modularization. This not only increases flexibility, but also helps in checking and resolving problems, memory leaks included.

If you do not break circular dependent packages, those behave very similar to one large, monolithic package!

Answer (score 1):

As well as using interfaces, you can often make structural improvements by moving classes between jars/packages. Breaking up fat classes so that common responsibilities can be more easily grouped together can help with this process. There are several commercial visualization/restructuring tools to help with this.